# IIS Sites Node Won't Expand

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

I added in a new website on my local IIS yesterday, IIS 8.5 on Win  8.1.

After I added it IIS hung indefinitely with the loading circle and I ended up having to kill it through Task Manager. That was late last night and I gave in and turned my computer off. This morning none of my sites work, all of them return `Not Found. HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.`.

When I open IIS and try to expand the Sites node underneath my local IIS I get the spinning circle that indicates loading but it never completes.

Is there some way to fix this without losing all of the sites I have set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can try to using a previous configuration, they are stored in 
`C:\inetpub\history`.
Copy the *.config files to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`, you may have to use the one before the last one (CFGHISTORY_000000xxxx), the last one is usually the current one.

If that doesn't help, copy those config backups somewhere else, re-install IIS and then restore a config backup.

Comment: Yep, I had to reinstall IIS but the config backup saved me a lot of effort. Thanks.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, [check out my answer to my own similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29267365/682480), as it might be of some help.