# Sites node does not expand in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, iis-8.5

I'm using **Windows 8** and **IIS 8.5** :

[image: iis about]

I've got a full install of IIS :

[image: windows features]

But, after adding 2 sites, all I see is this:

[image: iis node tree]

---

I've since removed and re-added the application pools, websites, and web applications many, many times. I also removed any modules I had installed like the **Transform Manager 1.1** and **URL Rewrite 2.0**.

Nothing seems to solve this issue.

FWIW, I saw [IIS Sites Node Won't Expand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28351914/682480), but the answer did not help me.  All of my history files seem to be corrupt as well.

Comment: Have you tried removing that Web.config file that it's referring to? Maybe there's something wrong with that config file, which is confusing IIS and causing the whole thing to blow up.

Comment: The config file is in production and 3 other environments and works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was that the **applicationHost.config** file was corrupted somehow. It wasn't getting deleted when I would uninstall / re-install IIS. Through some research, I found out that I needed to also uninstall the **Windows Process Activation Service** as well to reset that file as shown below :

[image: windows features screen shot]

Once I did that, everything was reset and I was back up and running with a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

My applicationHost.config file was corrupted in my case but not garbled.
I compared it to a server that had a working IIS8.5 manager and the

```
<Sites></Sites>
```

section was in the wrong place.

I copy pasted it to where it should be and the IIS manager sites tab now works fine.

Try that first or get an old applicationhost.config from the history section