# IIS does not contain Web Sites folder

Tags: iis

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloc/2008/02/06/the-message-received-from-the-server-could-not-be-parsed/) but I am unable to find *“Web Sites” folder* in IIS, and I tried to Google it, and I can't just find where this should be in my IIS manager. Is it because of a different version of IIS?

I can only see a folder called Sites, but it has no Properties option on right-click so I guess it is not the right one. This is how it looks:

[image]

Can anyone tell me if the information in that msdn blog post is still valid, and how to open Properties of WebSites in IIS?

Comment: are you not able to expand the sites? What do you see on the right pane when clicking on `Sites` inside the IIS Manager (inetmgr). Also check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351914/iis-sites-node-wont-expand

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer can you check now?

Comment: That post is for the obsolete IIS 6. Try to use Google to search for posts that apply to IIS 7 and above.

Comment: @LexLi I have succeded finding a solution for my problem, and your comment answers my question, so you can make it an answer, and I will mark it. Thank you!

Comment: I hope you answer it yourself. You did find the solution while I just gave you a hint.

Comment: which website folder you trying to get...not understand...

Comment: @piyushbarua the "Web sites" folder, which as you can see, it doesn't even exists for this version of IIS, I have added an answer exlaining that. Thank you!

Comment: than iis not installed properly please go to control planel and than program and feature and than add remove feature...now please select all inner options as well inside iis...

Comment: @piyushbarua it is installed properly

Comment: please check all inner option checkbox selected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LexLi have written in his comment:

*That post is for the obsolete IIS 6. Try to use Google to search for posts that apply to IIS 7 and above*.

So that solution was not a valid one in my case, as the IIS structure is different between the versions 6 and 7.